# How to have Desktop and Mobile Applications on Twitter

Tags: android, iphone, oauth, twitter, twitter-oauth

I would like to have a twitter connect on both my desktop and mobile applications. The problem is that for my desktop application I use the callback authentification. And for my mobile applications I use the Pin authentification. So when I connect my mobile app to twitter it is redirect to my website. Is it possible to use both of these options without creating two different applications?
Is anyone met this problem?

Answer (score 1):

So basically you would like to use the same consumer keys in both of your application with different callbacks?

If so, in your desktop application set the callback URL (`oauth_callback` parameter) to your website and in the mobile application set it to `oob`. (You can set these parameters in your requests, don't have to rely on the callback URL you explicitly entered in your app settings. Take a look on this part of the API doc: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth#registering-an-app). If this won't work (for example because Twitter does a check on if your application is mobile or desktop) then you will have to register two apps for this. And why wouldn't you do that, if you have two applications.

Comment: yes I want to use the same consumer key. I will try to do that. I didn't know that we could set the callback manually in the request instead of doing it in my application interface on twitter.

Comment: actually, there is another problem... when I set my oauth_callback to  'oob', it takes my default callback (http://mydomain.com/auth/twitter) and add 'oob' so I have http://mydomain.com/auth/oob... It really weird. I would like to have no default callback and set one when I need one but when I leave the callback field blank in my twitter application. Twitter deactivate the possibility to set a callback and send me an error.

Comment: Try it with removing the default callback URL in your application settings. After you did that make sure you always specify the callback URL (the url or oob) in your apps.

Comment: The problem is that when you remove the default callback URL in your application settings. Twitter deactivate the possibility to create a callback programmatically.